# How to fix: Npx create-react-app does not install everything only package.json and node modules

Tags: reactjs, command-line, create-react-app

I'm trying to create a new react app, but whenever I do npx create-react-app or npm init react-app, only the node_modules and a portion of package.json is installed.

```
npx create-react-app new-app
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSEr2.jpg) -> Current package.json and folder structure
Expected public folder and script run commands in package.json

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been two months, but I came across this exact issue and found the next solution:

You only need to update your npm and node modules, they are outdated for us or missing something important and that is why we get no template folders. Try below command:

```
run npm install -g update-node
run npm update npm -g
```

These two commands should fix it, if not, let me know, maybe I forgot one command to tell you.

Comment: Tried the above method, still got the same file structure. It seems that the process never advances beyond the vulnerability checkpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall react in case its installed globally by running the command "`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`". then run "`npx install -g create-react-app`".

npx comes with npm 52+ updated versions

Comment: `npx install -g create-react-app` didn't work for me, but `npm install -g create-react-app` did. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

tried using the above 2 commands and got created all the required folders under react app.
run npm install -g update-node
run npm update npm -g